# CloudKit public database reading without iCloud login

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, cloudkit

In the documents it says that CloudKit public databases will be available to read even if the user did not login with a proper iCloud account. However, I cannot fetch anything from my cloud database if i didn't connect my iOS simulator or device to iCloud. When i activate my iCloud account I am able to fetch data from my public database. If anyone who has an answer or same problem with me could answer that would be great. Thanks.

```
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"mycontainer"] publicCloudDatabase];
CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"idofmyrecord"] ;

[publicDatabase fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *fetchedRecord, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        NSLog(@"****Success***** %@",fetchedRecord[@"field1"]);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"****Failed***** %@",fetchedRecord[@"field2"]);

    }
}];
```

Comment: is container connection operatonal? I usually use [CKContainer defaultContainer]

Comment: I am using a different container because my data is stored at a different container. How can I change connection settings to allow access without iCloud account or can it be done? Thanks for help.

Comment: It should not be a problem to perform `fetchRecordWithID` method without be logged in, what does `containerWithIdentifier` return?

Comment: <CKContainer: containerInTheMemory; containerID=<CKContainerID: myContainerId; containerIdentifier=mycontainer, containerEnvironment="Sandbox">> this is what i get as a results of `po [CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"mycontainer"]`

Comment: I would check container's `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` method to see its status.

Comment: <CKError 0x7f85d86041f0: "Request Rate Limited" (7/2008); "This operation has been rate limited"; Retry after 3.0 seconds> This is the error I get with no iCloud account.
/////////////////////////////// This is the error if I try to fetch again.
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.apple.cloudd) UserInfo=userinfo {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.cloudd}

Comment: Lastly it says CKAccountStatusNoAccount as a CKAccountStatus, I am now investigating the bug if you have any additional comments please feel free to type it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

The public database is only readable with no login in the production environment, not in the development environment.

Apple's documentation says:

> In development, when you run your app through Xcode on a simulator or a device, you need to enter iCloud credentials to read records in the public database. In production, the default permissions allow non-authenticated users to read records in the public database but do not allow them to write records.

See [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html).

Comment: Can anyone confirm this is still valid in iOS 11 with Swift 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation is incorrect or this is a bug in Apple's code. You should file a radar at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking the same thing. I've tried this multiple times doing everything by the book and I'm just not having any success.

Comment: That's what I thought and typed earlier, I already opened up a bug report. Thanks, but this is not an answer it is just a comment please change it.

Comment: @JanderXlav if you did reported, then share the open radar link.

Comment: @ErsinSezgin Hi, did you report this bug? tnx

Comment: @ErsinSezgin have you tried this lately?, I just make a test fetching data without iCloud login and works for me

Comment: @user2924482 Actually after I failed to implement it with CloudKit, I created my own server to handle similar requests(and store data). Sorry, I didn't try it lately, hopefully they fixed it. I'll try it as soon as I finish my tasks.